# What is the chance of an infinitesimally small chance happening over infinite tries?

Tags: infinity

If you have an infinitesimal chance of succeeding at something, but you do it an infinite amount of times, what is the probability that you succeed at least once?

Comment: that's a question of limits of functions, for example if the chance of the thing not happening is $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n$ as n heads off to infinity we get $\frac{1}{e}$ so $1 - \frac{1}{e}$ could be an answer

Comment: In classical probability theory, a probability is a *real* number between $0$ and $1$, $0$ and $1$ included. Hence there is no such thing as an infinitesimally small (but non-zero) chance. What precisely do you mean?

Comment: @Bib-lost It was pretty much just a something I wondered after watching a YouTube video about infinitesimals, I guess if there is no such thing as an infinitesimally small chance then that is the answer

Comment: It is presumably possible to do probability with non-classical real numbers, but I'm not sure it would help much in practice.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, your comment reveals a vast ignorance of the subject.  Abraham Robinson's approach relies on *classical* logic, contrary to what your comment suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability based on infinitesimals is a well-established subject with a vast publication list.  Indeed it is possible to make sense of statements like "infinitely many trials, each with infinitesimal chance of winning, can have appreciable overall probability".  This approach was pioneered by de Mises and formalized by Edward Nelson.  The approach is "radically elementary" in the sense that it does not require complex developments in measure theory as other approaches to probability on continuous spaces do.  Just to mention a recent article, you could consult [this](https://eudml.org/doc/287881).